# Electric dryer runs but won't heat

Tags: electrical

Dryer Has 220 at outlet, checked each leg to ground and have 110. Checked other end of electric cord  on the dryer, no 220 across hot but have 110 to ground off each leg. Dryer turns but won't heat. Replaced dryer cord, same issue.

Comment: Have you measured hot-to-hot at the outlet?

Comment: Is this a 3 wire or 4 wire setup,   I could almost see breakers on the same phase but you said 220 at outlet or am I reading that wrong Something sounds unusual. But I had a friend that split his dryer breakers and the drum turns but no heat. The same as @jack suggested.

Comment: you have 0 Vac across the heating element

Comment: Did the dryer used to heat?

Comment: This is probably an easy one, but gonna need to see a description or photo of that breaker.  You can [edit] your question to add that info. Use the same browser you originally posted from, and if you want to use a different browser, tie your account to an email address and set a password and login with that from the other browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have 240 Volts across hot legs. Sounds like you're connected to the same hot leg in your panel. Check the voltage across the two breakers, or double pole breaker that the wires are attached to. You should get 240 Volts.